# Xcode "make" error

Tags: xcode, makefile

Since I updated to Xcode 7.2 I always get the following error when I try to compile a program using the `make` command:

```
iMac-de-Martin:~ Martin$ cd /Users/Martin/Desktop/iOS_OTA-Payload_Extractor-master 
iMac-de-Martin:iOS_OTA-Payload_Extractor-master Martin$ make
make: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild didn't return any data
make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
iMac-de-Martin:iOS_OTA-Payload_Extractor-master Martin$
```

I tried to reinstall the Command Line Tools but it didn't help.

Comment: What does `xcode-select -p` show?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: But do you know why I get this error then ? @trojanfoe